# R plot x-axis label show first and last value of domain

Tags: r, plot

either Im too stupid or it is not possible. For my plot check the following:

[image]

This is good already. However I need the labels on the x-Axis for the first and
last element. This means, according to the plot the labels should go from c1m1 to c1m31. Can I achieve this? Im already substituting the labels with the axis command via "at" and "labels". The values in between the borders are not that important, but the range of the curve needs to be clear.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code that you have used and sample of your data? [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you just need to suppress the x-axis on your original `plot`, and then specify a label with `axis` only for the first and last element. Like this: `plot(1:100, xaxt="n"); axis(1, at=c(1,100), label=c("A","Z"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply need to first plot the graph without x axis and then use the axis command to place labels where you want to

The following example shows how to use first and last element of an array

```
rainfall <- c(2, 5, 4, 5, 12)
days <- c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri")
plot (rainfall, xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=c(1,length(days)), lab=c(days[1], days[length(days)]))
```

will produce a plot with x labels only at the first and last data point. The key here is the `xaxt="n"` in `plot` command and the `axis` command on following line.

Pl. go through the tutorial at  http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/r/